# In Alabama, USA can someone 18 years old get on a plane without parents permission?

Tags: minor, travel, age, air-travel

My son, who will turn 18 this month said he wants to meet a girl he met online who lives in Indonesia. I said no, because even though he'll be 18 soon he is definitely no adult enough yet to travel to a foreign country by himself. We argued for about an hour and basically at the end he told me to go screw myself and he was gonna go anyways when he turned 18.

But once he's a legal adult I know I can't stop him. However, I'm fairly certain Alabama state law says that 19 years old is the age of consent and I think it's the legal age to move out. So would that also entail he can't leave home and board a plane without my permission?

And I had planned on going down to Florida this month with my son because my mom wants to see him on his birthday and stay a week then come back. Since the age in Florida is 17 I think could he just leave and I not be able to stop him?

Comment: As an aside, he should be certain that the girl is who she says she is.  There are many scammers on the internet (as well as law enforcement agents posing as children for the purpose of attracting pedophiles, though given your son's age that seems unlikely).

Comment: More to your point, even if the law says he needs your permission, you should think about the practical: will he at any point be asked to show that he has permission?  How would you enforce your denial of permission?  Such matters are perhaps better suited to [Travel.SE].

Comment: I'd definitely want proof that the person in Indonesia exists and is female. I wouldn't be surprised if it is some fat 40 year old bloke somewhere in Russia. And he should learn a bit of Indonesian, because many people won't understand him if he talks English. Tell him we have bets how long it takes from arriving to having his wallet stolen. Some love struck American teenager is what all crooks are waiting for.